# Cloud endpoint in Angular service

Tags: angularjs, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm trying to put the Google cloud endpoint api into the Angular service to make the logic clearer. But I dont know how to let the controller updates the model (value got from this service) when the cloud endpoint responses.
Here is the code:
Service:

```
angular.module('fooApp').service('FooService', function FooService() {
//variable to keep the data from server
var tl={};

this.retrieve=function(){

    //cloud endpoint api callback 
    var gapiCallback=function(){
        gapi.client.fooendpoint.foos.listFoos().execute( function(resp) {
                    tl=resp.items;
        });
    };

    var apiRoot='https://fooapp.appspot.com/_ah/api';
    gapi.client.load('fooendpoint', 'v1', gapiCallback, apiRoot);
};


this.get=function(){
    console.log(tl);
        return tl;
    }
  });
```

Controller:

```
angular.module('fooApp').controller('DeviceCtrl', function ($scope,FooService) {

FooService.retrieve();

$scope.myFoos =FooService.get();
```

});

View:

```
<ul class="nav nav-list">
    <li ng-repeat="t in myFoos ">
        <ul>
           <li >Foo attr1 = {{t.attr1}}</li>
           <li >Foo attr2 = {{t.attr2}}</li>
        </ul>
    </li>                                   
</ul>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the `FooService.get()` call in `$apply` to kick off a digest cycle so the UI will update.

```
$scope.$apply(function() {
    $scope.myFoos = FooService.get();
});
```